# call activity method after destroy

Tags: android, service, receiver

I'm using FCM to get Messages and a receiver to broad cast messages to my receiver

receiver code:

```
 public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private FCMInterface listener;

    public MessageReceiver(FCMInterface listener){

        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
   }
```

I'm using an interface to connect my receiver to activity(activity implements the FCMInterface)

question is what happens if activity onDestroy calls and after that i call a function of my interface?

Comment: you need checking activity.isFinishing() true or false for safe codeing

Comment: @RasoulMiri I wanted to know methods will call or not

Comment: It's very convenient, you just need to put a  Log.i("==","isCall");  in the function and see if it is printed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method implemented in the class get called even after the onDestroy() method got called.

But you can no longer access the activity context or anything related to UI.

While setting up the broadcast receiver you should register and unregister on start() and stop() life cycle callbacks. failing to do so will give you memory leak exceptions.

In good android programming practices, you would normally try to avoid situations where you hold the references of objects which are related to the activity context after the onDestroy() has been called.

Comment: so i can put a method in my interface to check activity is running or not, yes?

Comment: Yes surely, use isFinishing() in the interface method

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send intent to your activity (and set your activity singleTop or singleTask or SingleIntance if you need) instead of interface.

Comment: I have to send intent to activity using startActivity() but I want to update activity if its open else show notification or nothing